# Ruby on rails fetch name and show from the has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

we have user table and also wee have a country table the association is given as

```
user.rb

has_many :user_countries
has_many :countries, :through => :user_countries


user_country.rb

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :country

country.rb

has_many :users, :through => :user_countries
```

now what i want is to fetch the country name and show it into the sql record such that the new user_country column should come which will show the country of the user while fetching users

```
data = User.select("users.*, countries.name as country_name").
            joins("INNER JOIN `user_countries` ON `user_countries`.`user_id ` = `users`.`id`").
            joins("INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id ` = `user_countries`.`country_id`")
```

till now i am trying to do this but not succeeded it throws the mysql error . i need an extra column giving country_name as extra column. Please help me with this

Comment: this line is unclear/confusing `show it into the sql record such that the new user_country column should come which will show the country of the user while fetching users` what is the expected output?

Comment: I mean to say that if i run the raw sql query into  e.g  mysql  .therefore there should be an extra column in the user record named as country_name which will be attached at the end while fetching users

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: unknown column user_countries.user_id in 'on' clause

Comment: try this: `User.joins(:countries).select("users.*, countries.name as country_name")`

Comment: putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already using activerecord associations, you can use active record query as the following:

```
User.joins(:countries).select("users.*, countries.name as country_name")
```

You can learn more about select [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create a many to many relationship. This can be done very simply with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association.